Find and Replace in CKEditor 5 Plugin Pack is loading on a dropdown instead of dialog
I am using CKEditor 5 Plugin Pack V1.2.1 on a Drupal 10 website. Although stated in the documentation, Find and Replace opens in a dropdown. I have tried to disable Claro, use another theme but no luck. Any thoughts?

That documentation page does not say that find and replace opens in a dropdown, or I am reading it wrong.
